# running twitter php script through terminal

Tags: php, twitter, terminal

I'm trying to access a twitter account's information, but I keep running into this error:
Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in /Users/thegreenfrog/Desktop/twitter/tweet.php on line 33

I don't seem to see what's the problem, so I was hoping someone else did!

Thanks!

```
<?php

// Load the app's OAuth tokens into memory
require 'app_tokens.php';

// Load the tmhOAuth library
require 'tmhOAuth.php';

// Create an OAuth connection to the Twitter API
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
  'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
  'user_token'      => $user_token,
  'user_secret'     => $user_secret
));

// Send a tweet
// $code = $connection->request('POST',$connection->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array('status' => 'Hello Twitter'));
// // A response code of 200 is a success
//
// if ($code == 200) { 
// print "Tweet sent";
// }

// else{
// print "Error: $code";
// }

//Get @justinbieber's account info
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/users/show'), array('screen_name' => 'justinbieber’));
//Get the HTTP response code for the API request 

$response_code = $connection->response['code'];
// Convert the JSON response into an array
$response_data = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
// A response code of 200 is a success 

if ($response_code <> 200) {
print "Error: $response_code\n"; }
// Display the response array 
print_r($response_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dude,

you're using the wrong quotes

```
'justinbieber’));
```

and the wrong artist too. lol. kidding.

Replace it with:

```
$connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/users/show'), array('screen_name' => 'justinbieber'));
```

Comment: upvote for the artist stuff. oh and of course the answer too :P

Comment: Short(er) answer: don't write code in Microsoft Word.

Comment: haha yeah i know. It's just for testing. Thanks tho! it worked.